# reassemble binary after flow.js upload on node/express server

Tags: node.js, file-upload, asyncfileupload, flow-js

I can't figure out how to use the flow.js library with a node backend, and basing my code off the sample on the [flow.js](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js/blob/master/samples/Node.js/flow-node.js) github.

I'm getting the blob files up, but I'm not building the binary afterward the upload completes. The final get isn't getting triggered or my route is wrong:

```
  app.get('/download/:identifier', function(req, res){
    console.log('we writin')
    flow.write(req.params.identifier, res);
  });
```

anyone have any experience with this could get like a million stackoverflow pts because this seems to be a common issue when using node.js and flow.js and here are two other unanswered questions:

[Flowjs file upload - AngularJS and Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384222/flowjs-file-upload-angularjs-and-node)
[Reassembling file chunks produced in a multi-part upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093146/reassembling-file-chunks-produced-in-a-multi-part-upload)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a method that works but might not be the ideal approach.

Here I'm calling `flow.write` in `flow.post` if `status` is `done` and `currentTestChunk > numberOfChunks`. I do the greater than check because sometimes `flow.post` sends `status done` more than once as mentioned [here](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js/issues/17).

**Edit:** I added a way to clean the chunks after creating the file.

```
flow.post(req, function(status, filename, original_filename, identifier, currentTestChunk, numberOfChunks) {
        console.log('POST', status, original_filename, identifier);
        res.send(200);
        if (status === 'done' && currentTestChunk > numberOfChunks) {
            var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/' + filename);
            //EDIT: I removed options {end: true} because it isn't needed
            //and added {onDone: flow.clean} to remove the chunks after writing
            //the file.
            flow.write(identifier, stream, { onDone: flow.clean });            
        }            
    })
```

I had to modify `flow.post`'s callback to send `currentTestChunk` and `numberOfChunks`.

**File: flow-node.js**

```
$.post = function(req, callback){

//There's some codez here that we can overlook...

  fs.rename(files[$.fileParameterName].path, chunkFilename, function(){

    // Do we have all the chunks?
    var currentTestChunk = 1;
    var numberOfChunks = Math.max(Math.floor(totalSize/(chunkSize*1.0)), 1);
    var testChunkExists = function(){
          fs.exists(getChunkFilename(currentTestChunk, identifier), function(exists){
            if(exists){
              currentTestChunk++;
              if(currentTestChunk>numberOfChunks) {

                //Add currentTestChunk and numberOfChunks to the callback

                callback('done', filename, original_filename, identifier, currentTestChunk, numberOfChunks);
              } else {
                // Recursion
                testChunkExists();
              }
            } else {

              //Add currentTestChunk and numberOfChunks to the callback

              callback('partly_done', filename, original_filename, identifier, currentTestChunk, numberOfChunks);
            }
          });
        }
    testChunkExists();
  });
} else {
      callback(validation, filename, original_filename, identifier);
}
```

}

In flow.write call flow.clean with onDone if you want to remove the chunks.

```
  $.write = function(identifier, writableStream, options) {
      options = options || {};
      options.end = (typeof options['end'] == 'undefined' ? true : options['end']);

      // Iterate over each chunk
      var pipeChunk = function(number) {

          var chunkFilename = getChunkFilename(number, identifier);
          fs.exists(chunkFilename, function(exists) {

              if (exists) {
                  // If the chunk with the current number exists,
                  // then create a ReadStream from the file
                  // and pipe it to the specified writableStream.
                  var sourceStream = fs.createReadStream(chunkFilename);
                  sourceStream.pipe(writableStream, {
                      end: false
                  });
                  sourceStream.on('end', function() {
                      // When the chunk is fully streamed,
                      // jump to the next one
                      pipeChunk(number + 1);
                  });
              } else {
                  // When all the chunks have been piped, end the stream
                  if (options.end) {
                          writableStream.end();
                      }

                  //Options.onDone contains flow.clean so here I'm deleting all the chunked files.

                  if (options.onDone) {
                      options.onDone(identifier);
                  }
              }
          });
      }
      pipeChunk(1);
  }
```

Comment: Awesome!
Any chance you could submit a PR to the flow.Js github repo? here is a link: https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js/issues/17#issuecomment-49737531

Comment: Hey @flashpunk, I'll look into that when I get a chance.

Comment: I don't see how repeating the check, "if(currentTestChunk>numberOfChunks)", in the callback immediately after the first check can help fix the issue of the done status being triggered more than once.

Comment: The duplicate done status issue is logged here: https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js/issues/16.  It's been incorrectly marked as closed however the following comment looks like a much more likely fix: https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js/issues/16#issuecomment-50160924

Comment: @ChrisFoster it is a workaround and not a fix of the issue. When I observed status `done` getting sent more than once, currentTestChunk was not yet greater than numberOfChunks. So the check just ensures flow.write is executed when all chunks have been written. I try and keep sync code out as much as possible, which is the solution in the link you posted.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so i've been working on this and have come up with this, hopefully it will get someone started...

```
exports.post = function (req, res, next) {

    flow.post(req, function(status, filename, original_filename, identifier) {

        console.log('status: '+ status, filename, original_filename, identifier);

        if(status==='done'){

            var s = fs.createWriteStream('./uploads/' + filename);
            s.on('finish', function() {

                res.send(200, {
                    // NOTE: Uncomment this funciton to enable cross-domain request.
                    //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                });

            });

            flow.write(identifier, s, {end: true});
        }

    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've issued a pull request which adds reassembling logic to the Node example of Flow.js. See https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js/pull/71 and https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js/issues/17.